# Is it possible to manipulate jQuery Rendered Elements

Tags: jquery, slick.js

am using slick-slider and I beleive the next-prev and navigation dots are rendered by jQuery. Here is a screenshot of rendered elements.

```
<button class="slick-next slick-arrow" aria-label="Next" type="button" style="display: block;">Next</button>
```

Am trying to move some stuff around using Jquery, and am not able to connect to the elements that are rendered. 
Just want to confirm that it is or it is not possible to connect to those elements? am trying to do something simple like

```
jQuery( ".slick-next").addClass("test");
```

Comment: What does this mean " am not able to connect to the elements that are rendered"? Do you mean you can't locate them via a selector?

Comment: It's certainly possible to select elements that are on the page. You simply have to wait until they are on the page to try. Depending on what exactly you want to do with them,  you may be able to use an alternative method that doesn't require waiting.

Comment: after the elements are rendered am trying to do a simple jQuery( ".slick-next").addClass("test");

Comment: You don't appear to be waiting for them to "render"

Comment: @KevinB Understood, I have never had to do something like this.. would it be using .load(). would appreciate pointing me in the direction

Comment: No, you'd need to understand how the plugin creates the elements. events not provided by the plugin itself will not be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want to explore another option, Slick has built in functionality to customize mark up for the prev and next arrows.

```
$('.selector').slick({
  nextArrow: '<i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>',
  prevArrow: '<i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>',
// add the rest of your options here
});
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, appreciate it, I will try that. am also trying to move the location using append but it breaks...

Answer (score -1):

You could attach a mutation observer to the div that will hold your slider. Once it detects a mutation you can use it to look for the buttons and add the class.

I built something really quick here that you could take a look at (I used jQuery since that's what you seem to be using): https://jsfiddle.net/adsg3pr8/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery('#createDiv').click(function(){
    jQuery('<div>').appendTo('#changingContent');
  });

  MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;

  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
    jQuery(mutations[0].target).find('div').addClass('blue');
  });

  observer.observe(document.getElementById('changingContent'), {
    subtree: true,
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    characterData: true,
    attributeOldValue: true,
    characterDataOldValue: true
    });
});
```

Basically I attached the observer to a div and when I click on the button I add a child div to it. My observer watches this parent div and when it notices and change it add the "blue" class to any new div.

You'd have to make sure you code runs before your slick slider creates the slider.

Hopefully that helps.